# Sans serif and serif greek fonts in math expression

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I am wondering how to alternate sans and serif greek fonts within mathematical expressions. The package sansmathfonts changes the font to the whole document, which I don't want to. I have read related posts and I think one has to define a special math alphabet, say `\mathsfgreek`, in some sense similarly to

```
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{sans}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}.
```

I tried to use something like `\usefont` with similar parameters without success. I would like to have the choice between sans normal (upright), sans italic, sans bold normal, and sans bold italic, which should all be available in cmss. I would like to write something like

```
\[ \alpha\mathsfgreek{\alpha} \]
```

where `\alpha` on the left is normal and `\alpha` on the right is sans (upright). Can you give me some hint?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Declare a new symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfletters}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\salpha}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sbeta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sgamma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sdelta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sepsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\szeta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\seta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stheta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\siota}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\skappa}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\slambda}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smu}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\snu}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sxi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\spi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\srho}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ssigma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stau}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\supsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sphi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\schi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\spsi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\somega}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarepsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svartheta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarpi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarrho}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarsigma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarphi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"27}


\begin{document}

$\alpha\salpha\beta\sbeta\gamma\sgamma$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can define a `\msf` command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\msf}[1]{%
  \ifcat\noexpand#1\relax\msfgreek{#1}\else\mathsf{#1}\fi
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\msfgreek}[1]{\csname s\expandafter\@gobble\string#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\DeclareSymbolFont{sfletters}{OML}{cmbrm}{m}{it}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\salpha}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sbeta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sgamma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sdelta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sepsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"0F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\szeta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"10}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\seta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"11}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stheta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"12}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\siota}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"13}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\skappa}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\slambda}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"15}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\smu}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"16}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\snu}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"17}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sxi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"18}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\spi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"19}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\srho}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ssigma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\stau}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1C}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\supsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\sphi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\schi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\spsi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"20}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\somega}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"21}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarepsilon}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"22}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svartheta}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"23}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarpi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"24}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarrho}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarsigma}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"26}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarphi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"27}


\begin{document}

$\alpha\salpha\beta\sbeta\gamma\sgamma$

$\alpha\msf{\alpha}x\msf{x}$

\end{document}
```

Uppercase Greek is not covered, here. Exercise for the reader. `;-)`

Comment: Hi egreg, thank you for your reply. However, in your proposed method, I have to manually write a different name for the greek letter (e.g. `\ssigma` instead of `\sigma`). Is there a way to automate it? (e.g. writing `\mathsf{\alpha}` uses `\salpha` instead of `\alpha`: it seems to be a natural behavior for the `\mathsf` command, isn't it?).

Comment: It is OK with me to define all different commands, also for capital letters, but then eventually the end user shouldn't remember all the different cases (imagine having `\sSigma` and also `\supsigma` and so on). She should just write `\mathsf{\Sigma}` and get the capital, sans `\Sigma`. Then for upright letters there's a different new symbol font I guess. I can do it by myself if I have the command for the lower case letters.

Comment: Is it useful to use `\SetMathAlphabet`, e.g. something along the line of 

`\SetMathAlphabet{\mathsf}{normal}{\math@lph@encoding}{\mathsf@lph}{m}{n}` ? (just an idea)

Comment: @MonteCarlo No, it can't work.

Comment: Ok, so probably the only thing I can do is as follows (let me know your opinion): 0) use the new symbol font approach you proposed; 1) define a command `\sansfont` that can take latin or greek letters; 2) use `\ifcat\noexpand#1\relax` to check whether the argument is latin or greek (not very robust but it works as long as we are aware that the argument has to be a latin or greek letter); 3) if the argument is a latin letter, use `\mathsf`; 4) otherwise, modify (in some way I am unaware of) the argument (which is a greek letter) by adding an `s` at the beginning, e.g. from `\alpha` to `\salpha`

Comment: @MonteCarlo I implemented your idea.

Comment: Could you please expand on upper case Greek too (too hard an "exercise" alas). The `\msf{\Sigma}` command doesn't seem to work? Alternatively, should I just change `\DeclareMathSymbol{\schi}{\mathord}{sfletters}{"1F}`, presumably the last code? What the name of this "code", and where can I find a list (this one file:///home/matifou/Downloads/amssymb.pdf doesn't seem to have greek letters)? Thanks!!

Comment: @Matifou Did you try `\mathsf{\Gamma}`?

Comment: ok, much simpler indeed, thanks @egreg !