# Sans-Serif lower case Greek for mathpazo

Tags: greek, sans-serif, mathpazo

**Question:** Is it possible to get bold sans serif lowercase greek when the document is using mathpazo?

I have a problem with Sans Serif fonts in math environment when using mathpazo package.
The following MWE produces expected results for sans serif lower case greek \sigma , without mathpazo.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    $\bm \varepsilon$ \quad
    $\bm \sigma$ \quad
    $\sansmath{\bm \sigma}$
\end{document}
```

The result of above MWE is:

[image: Without mathpazo]

However, when using mathpazo

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    $\bm \varepsilon$ \quad
    $\bm \sigma$ \quad
    $\sansmath{\bm \sigma}$
\end{document}
```

The result is no Sans Serif for lower case greek:

[image: With mathpazo]

I am using sansmath package because the mathpazo Palatino package is missing sans-serif fonts (as mentioned [here](http://www.icl.utk.edu/~mgates3/docs/latex-fonts.pdf)).

Furthermore as mentioned in documentation [here](http://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/sansmath/sansmath.pdf), when using sansmath, since the OT1 text fonts do not provide the lower-case greek letters, one has to use package option [eulergreek] to take the lowercase greek from the Euler maths fonts. But even then it does not work.

I have been searching internet for more than a week, but couldn't find the solution.

The template for thesis uses mathpazo/Palatino, therefore I have to follow it, but additionally I need some sans serif lower case greek $\sigma$ and  $\varepsilon$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The package `sansmath` is used in order to get math symbols in a sans serif font; it should only be used in context where the whole document is sans serif.

Comment: The question is now clarified. Is it possible to get bold lower-case sans-serif greek alphabets when the entire document is using mathpazo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the greek commands (I use \ssigma here for the comparision).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathpazo}


\DeclareSymbolFont{EulerGreek}{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{EulerGreek}{normal}{U}{eur}{m}{n}

\SetSymbolFont{EulerGreek}{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\ssigma}{\mathord}{EulerGreek}{"1B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\svarepsilon}{\mathord}{EulerGreek}{"22}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}
    $\varepsilon \svarepsilon \bm \varepsilon \bm\svarepsilon $ \quad
    $\sigma \ssigma \bm \sigma \bm\ssigma$ 
\end{document}
```

A list for the glyph slots is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335857/2388.

[image]