# Execute list of commands generated by pairing elements from two \clist s or \seq s

Tags: fontspec, latex3, comma-separated-list, mapping, l3seq

I have hundreds of lines of code of the form

`` \Umathcode`a     = 0 \symwmb  "1D4B6 ``

and

`\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symrmtl  "0000B`

where, in the latter case, there is a counterpart `\def\alpha{^^^^03b1}`,
within commands of the type in David Carlisle's answer in [Greek letters within \mathsf, \mathsfit, \mathbfsf, and \mathbfsfit without using unicode-math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690558/greek-letters-within-mathsf-mathsfit-mathbfsf-and-mathbfsfit-without-usinthat) that map character codes to characters in various fonts.  Since I am reusing the Latin and Greek alphabets in several such commands, it occurs to me that it should be possible to create several globally-defined comma-separated  `\clist`s from LaTeX 3 code that is available in `xparse` (actually, from what I have read, `\seq`s may be more versatile in this case) and reuse them.  So I need to write a command of the form

`\MapCodes{LatinLower}{\symYYYY}{1D486, 1D487, 1D488,` ... `1D4CF}`

that can be called from within each of the `\symXXXX` commands in like those in David's answer to my previous question that would then execute this sequence of commands within the scope of the calling command.  Here, `LatinLower` is a list or sequence containing the Latin lowercase letters and could be globally defined, `\symYYYY` is the font declared with `DeclareSymbolFont{YYYY}{TU}{<NFSS family>}{m}{n}`, and the last argument is the list of slot numbers for the particular font which correspond to the lowercase characters desired.

I am pretty certain this is doable, but I am a newbie to LaTeX 3 and learn most easily by example anyway, so I can either spend all day trying to figure this out from `interface3.pdf` or just ask and learn from the answers.  I hope I have adequately explained what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: despite @egreg deleting his answer i'd go that way, there are only 24 "holes" for out of order characters so fixing them is less work than making explicit lists for all the alphabets

Comment: if you do want two lists see for example `\seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN ⟨seq1⟩ ⟨seq2⟩ ⟨function ⟩`  note the mapping is specified by unicode, it does not depend on the font

Comment: It must surely be easier to use unicode-math which already implements ths, then patch mtpro back

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I liked @egreg 's answer and got it to work.  It is certainly best for the Latin alphabet.  I was still curious about my original question thinking that was a functionality that I would need sooner or later (that is, pairing lists).  I found `\seq_map_pairwise_function` and got it to work for Greek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define sequences for the blocks and use `\seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN`.

Here I use just a short example. Use numeric codes (with the appropriate prefix).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\StixTwoMath}{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}[
  NFSSFamily=stix,
  Script=Math,
  Scale=MatchLowercase
]

\DeclareSymbolFont{stix}{TU}{stix}{m}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineblock}{mm}
 {% #1 = block name, #2 = clist
  \seq_gclear_new:c { g_pugh_math_block_#1_seq }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_pugh_math_block_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\definecodes}{mmm}
 {% #1 = block name, #2 = math family, #3 = clist
  \__pugh_math_definecodes:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__pugh_math_temp_seq
\tl_new:N \l__pugh_math_family_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pugh_math_definecodes:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__pugh_math_temp_seq { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__pugh_math_family_tl { #2 }
  \seq_map_pairwise_function:cNN
    { g_pugh_math_block_#1_seq } % the block
    \l__pugh_math_temp_seq % the codes
    \__pugh_math_assigncode:nn
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__pugh_math_assigncode:nn
 {
  \Umathcode #1 = 0 ~ \use:c { sym \l__pugh_math_family_tl } #2 \scan_stop:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineblock{LowerLatin}{`a,`b,`c}

\definecodes{LowerLatin}{stix}{"1D482,"1D483,"1D484}

\begin{document}

$abc+d$

\end{document}
```

Since I just specified a to c, only those characters receive a special `\Umathcode`.

[image]

Comment: Right. I actually meant to explicitly mention the possibility that the characters are not sequentially located within the font.  Blackboard characters for example often have C, N,  P, Q, R, and Z separated from the rest of the alphabet.  So I wanted to cover both cases.

Comment: Oh, but you are referring to the character codes, not the font slots.  So, right, this should work.

Comment: But I also want to work with the Greek alphabet, which has common variants noncontiguous with the usual characters, even though they have common character codes.  I modified the original question since it might also be an issue.

Comment: @MikePugh The new version should be like you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, again!