# ! Missing \endcsname inserted error when using \seq_map_pairwise_function:ccN

Tags: latex3, font-encodings, csname, mapping

This question is related to [Execute list of commands generated by pairing elements from two \clist s or \seq s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691745/execute-list-of-commands-generated-by-pairing-elements-from-two-clist-s-or-seq/691747?noredirect=1#comment1716526_691747).

I am trying to perform a sequence of commands of the form

`\def\alpha      {^^^^03b1}`

with `\seq_\map_pairwise_function:ccN`.  I would prefer to pass in arguments in the form `"03B1` rather than `^^^^03b1` and I think I have figured out how to do that.  This code appears to function correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\newfontfamily\mathematica{Mathematica}[%
    NFSSFamily=mathematica,Scale=MatchUppercase,%
    Extension=.ttf,%
    UprightFont=*,%
    BoldFont=*-Bold]
\DeclareSymbolFont{wm}{TU}{mathematica}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{wmb}{TU}{mathematica}{b}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symwm  "003B1
\Umathcode"03B2  = 0 \symwm  "003B2

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommandfunction}{mm}{\cs_set:cpn {#1} {\codepoint_generate:nn{#2}{11}}}

\mapcommandfunction{alphatwo}{"03B1}
\mapcommandfunction{beta}{"03B2}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    $$\alphatwo\beta$$
\end{document}
```

(substitute your font of choice).  But if I replace the code between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff` with

```
\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symwm  "003B1
\Umathcode"03B2  = 0 \symwm  "003B2

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommands}{mm}
{
    \seq_set_from_clist:cc {cmds}{#1}
    \seq_set_from_clist:cc {chars}{#2}
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:ccN{cmds}{chars}{\mapcommandfunction}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommandfunction}{mm}{\cs_set:cpn {#1} {\codepoint_generate:nn{#2}{11}}}

\mapcommands{alphatwo,beta}{"03B1,"03B2}
```

I get the error shown in the title.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how to discover it.  More specifically, I get

```
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \alphatwo,beta 
l.27 \mapcommands{alphatwo,beta}{"03B1,"03B2}
                                             
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `\seq_set_from_clist:cc {cmds}{#1}` has `cc` arguments, so both should be the name of a command, but you are passing in `alphatwo,beta`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ahhh...  Changed both to `cn` and it works!  Thank you!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually, in the larger program, I needed to change the second one back to `cc` to get it to work.  I'm sure I don't understand the distinction.  What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to watch the argument specifications to control expansion.

The first version works but defines

```
> \alphatwo=\long macro:
->\codepoint_generate:nn {"03B1}{11}.
l.22 \show\alphatwo
```

so the codepoint lookup happens every time it is used.

If you use `\cs_set:cpx` the lookup happens just once:

```
> \alphatwo=\long macro:
->α.
l.22 \show\alphatwo
```

Personally I would have used `\cs_set:Npx` and used  a syntax

```
\mapcommandfunction\alphatwo{"03B1}
```

as I don't see any advantage in using a name here rather than the token directly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\newfontfamily\mathematica[NFSSFamily=mathematica]{STIX Two Math}%

\DeclareSymbolFont{wm}{TU}{mathematica}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{wmb}{TU}{mathematica}{b}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symwm  "003B1
\Umathcode"03B2  = 0 \symwm  "003B2

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommandfunction}{mm}{\cs_set:Npx #1 {\codepoint_generate:nn{#2}{11}}}

\mapcommandfunction\alphatwo{"03B1}
\mapcommandfunction\beta{"03B2}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\alphatwo
\begin{document}
    $$\alphatwo\beta$$
\end{document}
```

Similarly in the second version

`\seq_map_pairwise_function:ccN`

an `N` should be a single token so `\mapcommandfunction` not `{\mapcommandfunction}` although an expl3 name would be more idiomatic.

`\seq_set_from_clist:cc`  the second `c` makes a csname from the whole of `#1` so it is never used as a list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\newfontfamily\mathematica[NFSSFamily=mathematica]{STIX Two Math}%

\DeclareSymbolFont{wm}{TU}{mathematica}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{wmb}{TU}{mathematica}{b}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn


\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symwm  "003B1
\Umathcode"03B2  = 0 \symwm  "003B2

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommands}{mm}
{
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_cmds{#1}
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn\l_chars{#2}
    \seq_map_pairwise_function:NNN\l_cmds\l_chars\mapcommandfunction
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommandfunction}{mm}{\cs_set:Npx #1 {\codepoint_generate:nn{#2}{11}}}

\mapcommands{\alphatwo,\beta}{"03B1,"03B2}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\show\alphatwo
\begin{document}
    $$\alphatwo\beta$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am not sure I would have gleaned these facts just from `interface3.pdf`.  And while there are lots of examples on the web, you usually only get a piece of the puzzle at a time.  Here, I got several at once.  Thank you!

Comment: I do have another question, though.  What happens if I attempt to pass in a command that has not yet been defined as, say, `\koppa` instead of `koppa`?

Comment: @MikePugh that works just as it's not an error to pass an undefined command to `\newcommand` as demonstrated here `\alphatwo`

Comment: I don't know if this is something I should post as a separate question; if so, I will.  I am getting errors like ```! LaTeX Error: Command `\Gamma` already defined.``` for all the usually defined capital Greeks. I'm guessing this is coming indirectly from the .cls file.  Is there a way to force redefinition?  I have tried using `\cs_undefine:N #1` inside the `\mapcommandfunction` just prior to `\cs_set:Npx` but that is either incorrect or doesn't work.

Comment: @MikePugh `\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}`  look at the location it is from `\begin{document}` not your code, `no-math` will fix

Answer (score 0):

I think that the specification with two separate `clist` that need to stay in sync will be hard to maintain and keep track of. Instead, I'd either suggest to drop the mapping variant and only use your `\mapcommandfunction`, or use `key=value` based input.

Also, just like @DavidCarlisle I don't see the advantage of inputting `alphatwo` instead of `\alphatwo`.

As a last note: Don't use `$$` for displayed maths in LaTeX, instead use `\[` and `\]`, or the `equation` environment, or the `amsmath` environments. `$$` can lead to inconsistent spacing and is not supported in LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{nopageno}

\newfontfamily\mathematica{Mathematica}[%
    NFSSFamily=mathematica,Scale=MatchUppercase,%
    Extension=.ttf,%
    UprightFont=*,%
    BoldFont=*-Bold]
\DeclareSymbolFont{wm}{TU}{mathematica}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{wmb}{TU}{mathematica}{b}{n}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\Umathcode"03B1  = 0 \symwm  "003B1
\Umathcode"03B2  = 0 \symwm  "003B2

\NewDocumentCommand{\mapcommandfunction}{mm}{\cs_set:Npn #1 {\codepoint_generate:nn{#2}{11}}}

\msg_new:nnn { mike-pugh } { missing-value } { Missing~ value~ for~ `#1'. }
\NewDocumentCommand \mapcommands { m }
  {
    \keyval_parse:nnn
      { \msg_error:nnn { mike-pugh } { missing-value } }
      { \mapcommandfunction }
      {#1}
  }

\mapcommands{\alphatwo="03B1, \beta="03B2}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[\alphatwo\beta\]
\end{document}
```