# Undefining/redefining already defined commands within expl3

Tags: macros, fontspec, expl3, plain-tex

I am not sure about the forum protocol regarding when to ask a new question and when to lump it in with an existing one, so I apologize if this is unorthodox.  The question stems from [! Missing \endcsname inserted error when using \seq_map_pairwise_function:ccN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691796/missing-endcsname-inserted-error-when-using-seq-map-pairwise-functionccn?noredirect=1&lq=1).  I have really just begun to explore `expl3`-style coding and I am far from a TeX guru, although I have been doing coding in other languages--obviously not typesetting languages--for many years.  But the whole token/input stream methodology is a completely new paradigm for me and I am trying to wrap my head around it.  The documentation is disseminated widely on the web, TeX books are few and getting harder to find (I actually bought Knuth's 5-volume set and Bechtolsheim's 4-volume set about a decade ago long before I got serious about this and they are currently in storage about a 1000 miles away), and I am consequently doing most of my learning by example, trial and error, and asking questions here.  So please bear with me.

The code in the above reference has issues without the `no-math` option being passed to `fontspec`.  Specifically, it has a problem with the common capital Greek letters having already been defined by `fontspec`.  Now, including the `no-math` option indeed solves the problem, but I am more interested in why this is happening and why there is apparently no way to undefine or redefine commands in `expl3`.  Or perhaps it is possible and I just haven't yet discovered how.  So, this particular set of questions is independent of the above reference other than its having provided the example.

What does `\cs_undefine` do if not undefine a control sequence?  What is its syntax?  I cannot seem to make it work with `\Gamma`, for instance, regardless of whether I use `:N` or `:c` or `\Gamma`, `{\Gamma}`, or `{Gamma}`.  The same is true for `\cs_meaning`, which I thought might help out with troubleshooting.  I must be missing something fundamental.  I am sure this could be done with plain TeX, but I get the impression from what I am reading that mixing the two is akin to dropping a self-modifying assembly routine into a C# UX application.  Hypothetically, and regarding this specific case, if I could *not* use the `no-math` option, and the capital Greeks were already defined, how would I remedy the problem?  More generally, how do you redefine a command that has already been defined with `expl3`?  I'm probably not even asking the right questions, but I hope that someone will be able to see where I'm failing to grasp something and steer me in the right direction.

Comment: You may need to post a minimal working example.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.
`\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_undefine:N \Gamma
\newcommand\Gamma{foo}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\Gamma
\end{document}`
works as expected no?

Comment: Similarly, the syntax for the csname version would be `\cs_undefine:c {Gamma}`.

Comment: The command you are using `\cs_set:Npx` is `\edef` and will redefine commands, as I commented on your last question the error was not coming from your L3 code but from fontspec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message is completely unrelated to `expl3` you have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage
%[no-math]
{fontspec}

\def\Gamma{wibble}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

which produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\Gamma' already defined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \begin{document}
                  
?
```

as at `\begin{document}` `fontspec` tries to adjust some settings, using latex2e declarations that check commands are new.

`no-math` tells the package not to do that.

Comment: Sorry.  I misinterpreted your comment in the other question to mean that `fontspec` was causing the problem because it had *already* defined these commands rather than that it was actually generating the errors because *it* was attempting to redefine them (which I am supposing it is doing in a `\AtBeginDocument` environment or similar construct).