# Why can these custom commands from packages not be seen in the main document?

Tags: package-writing, renewcommand

I am using TeX Live (MacTeX) 2023 with all updates (as of this morning). Consider two packages called `packageone.sty` and `packagetwo.sty`. `packageone.sty` contains a redefinition of `\vec` to include a starred version. `packagetwo.sty` contains a modified redefinition of `vec` to make the unstarred and starred versions identical if and only if `packageone.sty` is not loaded. For some reason, the custom `\vec` commands in each package cannot be seen from the main document and I do not understand why. The other commands defined in `packagetwo.sty` can be seen from the main document.

On one hand, I have been trying to understand this for the past two days and do not see anything obviously wrong because slightly different versions of the MWE have worked. On the other hand, I feel I am overlooking something obvious for some reason.

I was able to get the desired outcome by having `packagetwo` load `packageone` if it had not already been loaded (but that necessitated making the two new definitions of `\vec` identical, which is not a big deal in this case. They are different here merely for testing purposes). I was hoping to not make `packagetwo` load `packageone` but at least I now have a debugging strategy for figuring out why this extracted MWE doesn't work as I expected it to work.

Here is the MWE, which contains the two packages.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\begin{filecontents*}{packageone.sty}
\RequirePackage[g]{esvect}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{ s m e{_^} }%
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
      {%
        \vv{#2}%
        \IfValueT{#4}%
          {\sp{\,#4\vphantom{\smash[t]{\big|}}}}
      }%
      {%
        \symbfit{#2}
        \IfValueT{#4}%
          {\sp{#4\vphantom{\smash[t]{\big|}}}}
      }%
    \IfValueT{#3}%
      {\sb{#3\vphantom{\smash[b]{|}}}}
  }%
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{packagetwo.sty}
\IfPackageLoadedTF{packageone}
  {}%
  {%
    \RequirePackage[g]{esvect}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{}{Hello.}
    \RenewDocumentCommand{\vec}{ s m }
      {%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}
          {%
            \vv{#2}%
          }%
          {%
            \vv{#2}%
          }%
      }%
  }%

\NewDocumentCommand{\lhsmomentumprinciple}{ s }%
  {%
    \Delta
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
      {%
        \vec*{p}
      }%
      {%
        \vec{p}%
      }%
    \sb{\symup{sys}}%
  }%
\NewDocumentCommand{\rhsmomentumprinciple}{ s }%
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
      {%
        \vec*{F}%
      }%
      {%
        \vec{F}%
      }%
    \sb{\symup{sys,net}}\,\Delta t%
  }%
\NewDocumentCommand{\momentumprinciple}{ s }%
  {%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
      {%
        \lhsmomentumprinciple* = \rhsmomentumprinciple*%
      }%
      {%
        \lhsmomentumprinciple = \rhsmomentumprinciple%
      }%
  }%
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{packageone}
\usepackage{packagetwo}

\begin{document}
1 \( \vec*{E} \)\par
2 \( \vec{E} \)\par
\IfPackageLoadedTF{packagetwo}
  {%
    3 \( \momentumprinciple* \)\par
    4 \( \momentumprinciple \)\par
    5 \foo \par
  }%
  {}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: consider this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691822/

Comment: So the problem is `fontspec`, which is used by `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method to debug this sort of problems is to find out where the definition changes by planting `\ShowCommand` everywhere:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\renewcommand\vec{blub} % from package 1
\ShowCommand\vec
\renewcommand\vec{duck} % from package 2
\ShowCommand\vec
\begin{document} %what happens here??
\ShowCommand\vec
xxx
\end{document}
```

This will give answers like this (on the terminal or in the log):

```
> \vec=\long macro:
->blub.
<argument> \vec 
     

> \vec=\long macro:
->duck.
<argument> \vec 

> \vec=\protected macro:
->\Umathaccent fixed 7\symoperators "020D7\scan_stop: .
<argument> \vec
```

So obviously the definition changes in `\begin{document}`  again, and the `\Umath` points to unicode-math as "culprit". If you want to learn more you could then inspect the begindocument hook (with `\ShowHook{begindocument}`, or search for answers with unicode-math and begindocument. Or you simply do your redefinition in `begindocument` too.

Comment: Thank you for the debugging strategy.